# Save Textbox.text to a new Batchfile on my pc by button click

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file, onclick

How can i click a button on my **c# winform** and make it **save the contents of my textbox to a new batch file on my pc must save as a .bat and be able to open in windows8 as a .bat**

I have tried many solutions but none work i get a file *.bat but it wont open in windows8 and/or it is empty and has none of the text from textbox
please help and **please be gentle I have very little coding experience**.

currently trying this but no good please tell me where im going wrong google only has vb or irrelevant answers that dont seem to work in win8

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Progress.Value = 100;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\\MyBatchFile.bat");
    sw.WriteLine(ScriptWindow.Text);
    sw.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: must the filetype just be `.bat` or do you want to achieve anything else like returning the string as `echo` with a `break` after that?

Comment: Please specify clearly what is the error message that you get when you try to execute your bat file

Comment: Google is a useful tool... go here --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: what happens when you try to open it? how do you know that it's empty?

Comment: Maybe you can show us what `ScriptWindow.Text` is.

Comment: You're overengineering it.  `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\MyBatchFile.bat", ScriptWindow.Text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all the streamwriter junk--the beauty of .NET is that Microsoft has already built methods and functions that handle all of the low-level stuff that's required to write a simple text file, so it's a one-liner:

`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\MyBatchFile.bat", ScriptWindow.Text);`